# Underline not working in html2canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html2canvas

I'm having trouble getting html2canvas to underline text. From my understanding of the package, underline is supported. I am able to save the image and have not had problems with any other CSS attributes. Any thoughts?

Here is my test code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function save(div)
{
        html2canvas([document.getElementById('img')], { background:'#fff',   
            onrendered: function(canvas)  
            {
                var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
                $.post("save.php", {data: img, prefix: 'test'});   
            }
        });         
}

-->
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">


<div id="img" style="background-color:white; width:304px; float:left; height:104px; border-radius:10px; border:3px solid white;">
<div style="width:125px;"></div>
<div style="width:175px; padding:0px;">
<u>Test</u>
<span style="text-decoration:underline;">Test2</span>
</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onClick="save();" value="Save!">
<br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `for (var i=1;i <= 1;i++)` action is performed just once, so why use a loop at all ?

Comment: You're right it's not necessary in this test code. I had left it in there from when I actually used it. Updated the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if converting:

```
 $.post("save.php", {data: img, prefix: 'test'});
```

to:

```
var tempObj = {prefix:'test'};
tempObj[data] = img;
$.post("save.php", tempObj);
```

helps, because I once had problem when I had two variables in like `data: img` as key-value pair and had solved using `tempObj[data] = img` instead. See if it works.

Also, your whole JS is inside `<!--` which will definitely cause SyntaxErrors.